# python twisted: Deferred function not run immediately?

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

i have recently read the official docs about python twisted framwork.
Now ,i can clearly understard "What Deferreds don't do: make your code asynchronous",When you call a blocking function,you need "The twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread" function to set up a thread to run the blocking function .

I wrtite the following demo to make a test:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor,defer,threads
import time
def delay(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return "Time to wake up,you havs sleep %s second!" % x

def getres(res):
    print res
    reactor.stop()

d = threads.deferToThread(delay,3)
d.addCallback(getres)
print "Now my pieces of code not blocking!"

import time
time.sleep(3)
print "now to get the result of the delayed fuction"
reactor.run()
```

But the result i got is out of my expection:

```
(myspace) [root@master myspace]# python ttt.py 
Now my pieces of code not blocking!
now to get the result of the delayed fuction
Time to wake up,you havs sleep 3 second!
```

Why there still has 3 seconds delay after output the second line("now to get the result of the delayed fuction") instead of output the third line immediaty .
    i do not know why my code sleep 6 seconds in total ,Doesn't it have to be 3 seconds?if it have to be 6,is that to say "deferred only delayed the blocking funciton,not run the function right after d.addCallback(getres)"?
   if i want to only be 3 secondes delay ,what can i do .
   your answer will be hightly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about Twisted at all, but I'd guess (based on experience with other frameworks) that *nothing* happens within the framework until the `reactor.run` line at the end kicks off its internal event loop. If your other code (calling `deferToThread`, printing "not blocking", etc) was run in a callback from Twisted code, I suspect it would work the way you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Your code goes through two `sleep(3)`. One before you even start the reactor and get Twisted running. The other one is in the `delay` function.

Now after waiting 3s for the first time, the reactor gets started. This is the point where the thread is actually starting as well. About 3s later it returns and the result is printed. Should take a bit more than 6s all together.

Or in short: Twisted does not do anything before the reactor is running.

Comment: Many thanks. I think i should avoid writing code like time.sleep(3) in my main code.

Comment: You should avoid blocking calls at all. Use `reactor.callLater(3, your_function, args...)` instead. It will queue `your_function(args...)` to run in 3 seconds and continue immediately.